# Cant seem to get my ifstream and ofstream to work properley when using getline() and Ignore() functions Cant Use Loops or Arrays ect

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I cant read in the integers after my getline() reads in the string. I have to read in the whole entire name from a data file, then read in the pay rate, then the number of dependants, and then the percentage of gross. I can use Arrays loops vectors or anything of that sort. I can only use the getline() and Ignore() functions or something similar to that. So my question is where am I going wrong here?

**Here is what the data file looks like (I only coded for it to read in one person):**

> John W. Smith
>
> 12.55
>
> 3
>
> 5
>
> Mary Anderson
>
> 11.75
>
> 1
>
> 8
>
> Brad W. Baker
>
> 11.75
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> Heather Johnson
>
> 13.25
>
> 2
>
> 10

**Here is my code so far:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream indata;
    ofstream outdata;
    string fname, lname;
    int hours;
    hours = 0;
    outdata.open("Weeklypay.dat");
    double payrate;
    double gross;
    double taxes;
    double ssecurity;
    int dependants;
    double retirement;
    double net;
    double percgross;
    int insurance;

    indata.open("Pay.dat");
    getline(indata, fname);

    cout << "Please enter the total hours worked for " << fname << endl;
    cin >> hours;
    indata >> payrate >> insurance;
    gross = payrate * hours;
    taxes = 0.23 * gross;
    ssecurity = 0.08 * gross;
    dependants = 12 * insurance;
    indata >> percgross;
    retirement = percgross * gross / 100;
    net = gross - taxes - ssecurity - dependants - retirement;

    cout << fname << "'s net pay is: $" << net << endl;
    outdata << fname << endl;
    outdata << "Gross Pay: $" << gross << endl;
    outdata << "Taxes: $" << taxes << endl;
    outdata << "Social Security: $" << ssecurity << endl;
    outdata << "Insurance: $" << dependants << endl;
    outdata << "Retirement: $" << retirement << endl;
    outdata << endl << endl;
    outdata << "Net Pay: $" << net << endl;
    outdata << endl << endl;

    // Next person here:

    cin.ignore(10, '\n');
    getline(indata, fname);

    cout << "Please enter the total hours worked for " << fname << lname << endl;
    cin >> hours;

    indata >> payrate;
    gross = payrate * hours;
    taxes = 0.23 * gross;
    ssecurity = 0.08 * gross;
    indata >> insurance;
    dependants = 12 * insurance;
    indata >> percgross;
    retirement =  percgross * gross / 100;
    net = gross - taxes - ssecurity - dependants - retirement;

    cout << fname << lname << "'s net pay is: $" << net << endl;
    outdata << fname << lname << endl;
    outdata << "Gross Pay: $" << gross << endl;
    outdata << "Taxes: $" << taxes << endl;
    outdata << "Social Security: $" << ssecurity << endl;
    outdata << "Insurance: $" << dependants << endl;
    outdata << "Retirement: $" << retirement << endl;
    outdata << endl << endl;
    outdata << "Net Pay: $" << net << endl;
    outdata << endl << endl;

     indata.close();
     outdata.close();

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "where am I going wrong"? *What's* wrong?

Comment: Well its not reading in the pay rate or the number of dependents, or the percentage of gross from the data file. It only reads in the whole name John W. Smith. I end up with a wierd calculation.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But remember that you have to elaborate the problem you are experiencing in your post. It facilitates the process of determining the cause of the problem and it's much more convenient IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `retirement = percgross * gross;` to `retirement = percgross * gross / 100;` You read in the percentage  of gross, and multiply it directly, then the `retirement` is bigger than `gross`.
**EDIT:**
for the multiple persons scenario, use a loop statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream indata;
    ofstream outdata;
    string fname, lname;
    int hours;
    hours = 0;
    outdata.open("Weeklypay.dat");
    double payrate;
    double gross;
    double taxes;
    double ssecurity;
    int dependants;
    double retirement;
    double net;
    double percgross;
    int insurance;

    indata.open("Pay.dat");

    while(getline(indata, fname) )
    {
        if(fname.empty() )
            continue;
        cout << "Please enter the total hours worked for " << fname << endl;
        cin >> hours;
        indata >> payrate >> insurance;
        gross = payrate * hours; //690.25
        taxes = 0.23 * gross;//158.75
        ssecurity = 0.08 * gross;//51.7
        dependants = 12 * insurance;//3
        indata >> percgross;
        retirement = percgross * gross / 100;//34.51
        net = gross - taxes - ssecurity - dependants - retirement;

        cout << fname << "'s net pay is: $" << net << endl;
        outdata << fname << endl;
        outdata << "Gross Pay: $" << gross << endl;
        outdata << "Taxes: $" << taxes << endl;
        outdata << "Social Security: $" << ssecurity << endl;
        outdata << "Insurance: $" << dependants << endl;
        outdata << "Retirement: $" << retirement << endl;
        outdata << endl << endl;
        outdata << "Net Pay: $" << net << endl;
        outdata << endl << endl;

    }

    indata.close();
    outdata.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that helped out with the calculation, but now when i add another person with the same code copy and pasted below it. It wont read the next name and the numbers on the file. I posted the code now

Comment: ohh, you just need a loop to solve your problem. Don't use copying & pasting programming, see the edit.

Comment: I cant use loops. I can only use the getline() or Cin.ignore and ifstream extractions. i should be able to use cin.ignore(10, '\n'); before my new get line so that it ignores the return delimeter. Its not allowing me to do this.

Comment: @user3312523 Did your teacher explicitly forbid the use of loops?, which is a fundamental programming practice for beginners?

Comment: No we actually have not gotten to loops yet. I told my teacher i could do it with a loop, and my teacher said, "That's good. Now do it without a loop." So now i'm in this predicament.

Comment: Also that while loop wont work. All it does when i compile it, is repeat the same name and same pay rate ect...

Comment: @user3312523 Then put the input/output in a function and call it 4 times.

Comment: ahh okay, well i figured it out finally. instead of using cin.ignore i had to use indata.ignore(2, '\n'); then use my getline. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: the while loop works on my machine, for all the persons, I input 55 hours, the output is here:http://codepad.org/Rb55UTuO